# Updated Syntax for @Parent() in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am looking at a sample for angular2 where a class constructor references @Parent().  I get a Error:(58, 18) TS2304: Cannot find name 'Parent'. I saw another answered questioned that said to use 'Host' but I got the same error. I'm using Alpha.45.  [Here](http://blog.thoughtram.io/angular/2015/04/09/developing-a-tabs-component-in-angular-2.html) is a reference to the sample. Full code is at the end.

```
constructor(@Parent() tabs:Tabs) {
        tabs.addTab(this);
        this._active=true ;
    }
```

Comment: What same error do you get when you use `@Host()`? `@Parent` was deprecated a lot of alphas ago, and you must use `@Host`. So the exact error and a reproduction of the error would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`@Host`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L237) parameter decorator just restrict the dependency resolution with the host component. You don't have to use it to get the closest component of specified Type. However, you may need to use [`@Inject`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/di/metadata.ts#L44) with [`forwardRef`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/2.0.0-alpha.46/modules/angular2/src/core/di/forward_ref.ts#L42) if your dependency isn't yet defined.

For example (see [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/HzyOuwqpXeuHBm4Ei6nZ?p=preview), I don't use `forwardRef` there):

```ts
import {Component, Input, Inject, forwardRef} from 'angular2/angular2'

@Component({
  selector: 'tab',
  template: 'Tab {{ index }}'
})
class Tab {
  @Input() index: number;

  constructor(@Inject(forwardRef(() => Tabs)) tabs: Tabs) {
    console.log(tabs);
  }
}

@Component({
  selector: 'tabs',
  template: 'Tabs (<ng-content></ng-content>)'
})
class Tabs {}

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  directives: [Tabs, Tab],
  template: `
    <tabs>
      <tab index="1"></tab>
      <tab index="2"></tab>
    </tabs>
  `
})
export class App {}
```

Comment: The plunker was very useful. Thank you.